# Is there a generalization of Burnside's theorem for compact Lie groups?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Recall the following theorem due to Burnside:Let $G$ be a finite group and let $V$ be its  irreducible complex representation of dimension greater than 1, then the character
of this representation is $0$ on some element of $G$. Is this statement still correct
if $G$ is any compact Lie group? Thanks.

Comment: Some context for the question would be helpful.   It seems to reduce to looking at the well-studied finite dimensional representations (over `$\mathbb{C}$`) of a connected semisimple compact Lie group. Why would an answer be interesting? There are similarities with the finite group situation, including orthogonality relations, but also some big differences. As far as I can see, the proof for finite groups doesn't readily translate to compact Lie groups. The answer could well be yes (or no), but does it have implications? 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes--use the Weyl character formula, for example.
See: [Patrick X. Gallagher, Zeros of group characters. Math. Z. Volume 87 (1965), Number 3.](http://www.springerlink.com/content/l2m14425071477x3/)

Comment: Gallagher's proof combines Burnside's theorem with Weyl's character formula, using some Clifford theory.   Since finite groups are also compact, it's probably not realistic to expect a general proof to give a new or simpler proof of Burnside's result.   (By the way, Gallagher has spent his career at Columbia, serving as the adviser of Dorian Goldfeld among many others.)  

Comment: The link to the paper at `springerlink.com` is broken, but it can also be found at [doi:10.1007/BF01111717](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01111717). Corresponding zbMATH Open review is at [Zbl 0128.25602](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0128.25602).